# qos method call using DateTime and Stopwatch

Tags: c#, datetime, timer

I need to limit method call to 80 times per second (for each `connectionId`).

My initial version:

```
private const int MAX_TRANSACTIONS_PER_PERIOD = 80;
private const int PERIOD_IN_MS = 1000;
private Queue<DateTime>[] times = new Queue<DateTime>[10]
{
    new Queue<DateTime>(100),
    new Queue<DateTime>(100),
    new Queue<DateTime>(100),
    new Queue<DateTime>(100),
    new Queue<DateTime>(100),
    new Queue<DateTime>(100),
    new Queue<DateTime>(100),
    new Queue<DateTime>(100),
    new Queue<DateTime>(100),
    new Queue<DateTime>(100)
};

private int ExecTransWithStats(int connection_id, string name, string parameters_string, byte[] bytes)
{
    DateTime nowTime = DateTime.Now;
    while (times[connection_id].Count > 0 && (nowTime - times[connection_id].Peek()).TotalMilliseconds >= PERIOD_IN_MS)
    {
        times[connection_id].Dequeue();
    }
    if (times[connection_id].Count >= MAX_TRANSACTIONS_PER_PERIOD)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(PERIOD_IN_MS - (int) (nowTime - times[connection_id].Dequeue()).TotalMilliseconds);
    }
    times[connection_id].Enqueue(DateTime.Now);

    return ExecTrans(connection_id, name, parameters_string, bytes);
}
```

I've decided to replace `DateTime` with `Stopwatch` just because I don't need to store entire `Date`.  I only need to store how many milliseconds elapsed:

```
private const int MAX_TRANSACTIONS_PER_PERIOD = 80;
private const int PERIOD_IN_MS = 1000;
private Queue<long>[] times = new Queue<long>[10]
{
    new Queue<long>(100),
    new Queue<long>(100),
    new Queue<long>(100),
    new Queue<long>(100),
    new Queue<long>(100),
    new Queue<long>(100),
    new Queue<long>(100),
    new Queue<long>(100),
    new Queue<long>(100),
    new Queue<long>(100)
};

private Stopwatch workingTime = Stopwatch.StartNew();

private int ExecTransWithStats(int connection_id, string name, string parameters_string, byte[] bytes)
{
    long nowTime = workingTime.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    while (times[connection_id].Count > 0 && (nowTime - times[connection_id].Peek()) >= PERIOD_IN_MS)
    {
        times[connection_id].Dequeue();
    }
    if (times[connection_id].Count >= MAX_TRANSACTIONS_PER_PERIOD)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(PERIOD_IN_MS - (int) (nowTime - times[connection_id].Dequeue()));
    }
    times[connection_id].Enqueue(workingTime.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    return ExecTrans(connection_id, name, parameters_string, bytes);
}
```

Am I correct that version with `Stopwatch` is better? It has much better precision, but I'm ok  with having precision of `DateTime` (10-15 ms). Do I pay for extra precision (which I don't actually need)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`StopWatch` is definitely better for timing stuff, but the semantics of the two versions are different. With `DateTime` you have this:

```
private int ExecTransWithStats(int connection_id, string name, string parameters_string, byte[] bytes)
{
    DateTime nowTime = DateTime.Now;
   ...
```

and with `StopWatch` you have that:

```
private Stopwatch workingTime = Stopwatch.StartNew();
private int ExecTransWithStats(int connection_id, string name, string parameters_string, byte[] bytes)
{
    long nowTime = workingTime.ElapsedMilliseconds;
  ...
```

#### Bug?

The stopwatch starts as soon as the instance is created, it looks like you're misusing the stopwatch.

```
long nowTime = workingTime.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

That's not how a stopwatch works. That will give you the number of milliseconds elapsed between the instantiation of your class and the moment `ExecTransWithStats` gets called. I doubt this is what you are expecting.